# RegEx taking too much time and memory

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this RegEx pattern

```
    ^(\\d|\\w)+\\..*
```

and this is my input

```
    (1) nu11111111111111
    (2) nu1111111111111111111
    (3) nu1111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Time has taken by input 2 is higher than input 1 and It returns **Not Matched** result. But for input 3, I didn't get any response even after 30 min of execution. I am observing the memory as well and it increases continuously.

Below is my code snippet:

```
    String input1 = "nu11111111111111";
    String input2 = "nu1111111111111111111";
    String input3 = "nu1111111111111111111111111111111111111";
    try
    {

        if (input3.matches("^(\\d|\\w)+\\..*"))
        {
            System.out.println("Matched");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Matched");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: 30min for such a short input, yeah you probably have a problem

Comment: `(\\d|\\w)` is a redundant, `\\d` is already include in `\\w` - so just use `\\w`. Probably a backtracking issue, though it's a little excessive for the shown case.

Comment: 30 min? It's indeed not a fast regex, but on [this online compiler](https://tio.run/##lY49b8IwEIb3/IqTJ7sIS5QRdWSEBTZMpcNxwSFxovgCRWl@e5oPFAlBBm7we7p7/OgivOA0Cs91nRWH2GrQMXoPK7SuDADuQ09ITVxSG0LSrPiGcuuOuz1gfvSiJQH6GViXFTSDL2CumD0UWzxxn6@4MXg@Co9@p/zWZRl00Zb9Ad7rZIKkT8Zz9s2VCv@UuoqJUlJ@MCEGvhy67p6bJ5PItCCZNZdR7DhbdZqQicWAVkNnYm/ecK1TglFf/@p2DXz5q01GNnVgRPAoN71vQ6jP2xy14XdVK6iCqq7/AQ) it's 0.9 seconds to execute your code.. Is something else running and taking all your memory locally?

Comment: Also, why is there a `[tag:perl]`..?

Comment: And what is the actual question? I can't find any...

Comment: @SebastianProske: Not so excessive, 2^37 possibilities for the 1s in example 3).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's what I figured after it was too late to edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is another case of catastrophic backtracking, as `\d` is already included in `\w`. As there is no match to be found, the regex engine tries to backtrack into every possible combination of matching either `\w` or `\d` against your series of `1`s - which is quite a lot.

To get a little insight into what is happening, see https://regex101.com/r/4fRRpc/1/ and go to the regex debugger. This uses a PCRE pattern without startup optimizations, which should be pretty similar to what java appears to do in this case.

For your regex, use `^\\w+\\..*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

That Java regex engine is pathetic.

```
› time perl -E'say /^(\d|\w)+\..*/ ? "Matched" : "Not Matched" for qw(nu11111111111111 nu1111111111111111111 nu1111111111111111111111111111111111111)'
Not Matched
Not Matched
Not Matched

real    0m0,009s
user    0m0,006s
sys     0m0,003s
```

Try [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2), it does not backtrack and has Java bindings.